# Wrapping around negative numbers in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm rewriting C code in Rust which heavily relies on `u32` variables and wrapping them around. For example, I have a loop defined like this:

```c
#define NWORDS 24
#define ZERO_WORDS 11

int main()
{
    unsigned int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < NWORDS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (j < (i-ZERO_WORDS+1)) {
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the `if` statement will need to wrap around `u32` for a few values as initially `i = 0`. I came across the [`wrapping_neg` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.wrapping_neg) but it seems to just compute `-self`. Is there any more flexible way to work with `u32` in Rust by also allowing wrapping?

Comment: Either use the [`Wrapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.Wrapping.html) wrapper, or use appropriate functions, like `wrapping_sub` or `wrapping_add`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, `wrapping_sub` worked for my case. If you can write it as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140355/wrapping-around-negative-numbers-in-rust#comment83258504_48140355), the literal answer to your question is to use [`u32::wrapping_sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.wrapping_sub) and [`u32::wrapping_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.wrapping_add):

```
const NWORDS: u32 = 24;
const ZERO_WORDS: u32 = 11;

fn main() {
    for i in 0..NWORDS {
        for j in 0..i {
            if j < i.wrapping_sub(ZERO_WORDS).wrapping_add(1) {}
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'd advocate avoiding relying on wrapping operations unless you are performing hashing / cryptography / compression / something similar. Wrapping operations are non-intuitive. For example, `j < i-ZERO_WORDS+1` doesn't have the same results as `j+ZERO_WORDS < i+1`.

Even better would be to rewrite the logic. I *can't even tell* in which circumstances that `if` expression will be true without spending a lot of time thinking about it!

It turns out that the condition *will* be evaluated for `i=9, j=8`, but not for `i=10, j=0`. Perhaps all of this is clearer in the real code, but devoid of context it's very confusing.

This appears to have the same logic, but seems much more understandable to me:

```
i < ZERO_WORDS - 1 || i - j > ZERO_WORDS - 1;
```

Compare:

```
j < i.wrapping_sub(ZERO_WORDS).wrapping_add(1);
```